# Python: asyncore & other threads

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, asyncore

I am new to using asyncore in python.

In my current setup, I'm using asyncore's loop on its own thread. On that thread, I previously created a server socket.

Just like in the examples, I accept incoming connections and spawn a handler. However, unlike the example, my connections aren't simple queries: they're connections to a messaging server.

This means that, while a handler object is alive and waiting for more data (and we've reached a quiescent state), another thread may receive an event (like a process just finishing) and wish to send some data out on those sockets.

However, if (on the calling thread) I do "sent = self.send(data)", the variable "sent" ends up being None... even though the socket is still alive and everything.

Just to be extra clear, when I call send, here's a good representation of stack traces of each thread:

```
Thread N:
myThreadMain
asyncore.loop()

Thread M:
.....
processDidExit
Messaging.sendMessage
ConnectionHandler.handleMessage
self.dispatcher_with_send::send(msg)
```

(Note that I used the C++ notation there just to indicate that ConnectionHandler.handleMessage was invoking its superclass's send method.)

Like I said, that send method returns None, 'writable' is never called, and neither is 'handle_write'. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong... Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `asyncore` is **really** long in the tooth -- decades! -- and hardly maintained any more.  Consider updating to Python 3 and https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html ...!